# How to add a validation that accepts only years above a certain value, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, testing, model

Currently I have the following:

```
validates :year, presence: true
```

However, I need this to validate only years later than 1960. I also don't want to have to manually input all of the years and have it reject only years that are within a range. Also, years should not be valid if greater than the present year.

Comment: What `type` is `year`?

Comment: integer (numericality)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`numericality`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) validator should work here:

```
validates :year, 
  numericality: { greater_than: 1960, less_than_or_equal_to: -> { Date.current.year } }
```

Comment: Is it the same for rails 4? I think it would have to be `validates :year, numericality: { greater_than: 1959, less_than:  Date.current.year+1 }`

Comment: Also, wouldn't it have to be less than next year (in order to include the present year), and greater than 1959 (to include that 1960)?

Comment: @modulus, please use `less_than_or_equal_to` instead of `less_than`.  Updated answer to reflect this, sorry I misread it earlier!

Comment: so I have `validates :year, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1960, less_than_or_equal_to:  Date.current.year }` and that works :)

Comment: I am on Rails 6, it doesn't work with lambda, but it does with Proc:

`validates :year, 
  numericality: { greater_than: 1960, less_than_or_equal_to: Proc.new {|record| Date.current.year } }`

Using `Date.current.year` is not correct since in production classes are cached and therefore value is computed only on boot.